# How to set PHP class property from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, class, properties, getter-setter

How would I set a property or variable of a PHP class from JavaScript code that uses it. The class is pretty basic, and looks something like this:

```
    <?php

    class_exists('api') or die();

    class className extends someOtherClass
    {
        public function __construct(...
        {
            parent::__construct('1.0', ...
        }

        public $publicVariable = "initBlank";

        public function Init()
        {
            parent::Init();
            $this->Set...
            $this->Add...
        }

        public function someFunction()
        {
            ...
            ...
            return array(...
        }   

    }

    return new className($this);
```

And the calling JavaScript code is also very basic:

```
    function classView()
    {
        this.var1 = ko.observable(0);
        this.var2 = ko.observable('');
    }

    classView.prototype...
    classView.prototype...

    classView.prototype.clickBtn = function ()
    {
        this.publicVariable = "myValue";
        ...
        ...
    };
```

Is there any way to set the ***$publicVariable*** property from the JavaScript code?

Thank you.

Comment: You could use AJAX to send the data to PHP, then set the property accordingly.

Comment: Hi Crackertastic, and thank you for your answer. How could I do that?

Comment: `$.ajax()` with zepto or jQuery

Comment: @iSofia You can use a JS library like [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) or if you prefer native JS you can work with an [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) object instead.  Basically you are going to make an asynchronous call to your PHP script and then when PHP is finished any response can be captured with a callback in JS.

Comment: Hi rogelio. This is for a plugin in a webmail client, and I don't think that I could use jQuery or even XHR for that matter. They have provided a proprietary mechanism to send AJAX requests to the class using the ***AddJsonHook*** function.

Comment: Yes, you're right Crackertastic. But those may not be available to me. How would I adapt the ***AddJsonHook*** function for sending such a request? It already sends AJAX requests to functions in the PHP class.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a *preprocessor* which means that the Web server (e.g. Apache) executes the PHP and returns the result to the client. Therefore, it is impossible to dynamically update PHP variables via client-side JavaScript.

However, you can execute an AJAX request to store the variable on the server somewhere and then access it from PHP.

Comment: Hi tdlive aw'sum, and thank you for your answer. I currently use the ***AddJsonHook*** function to map PHP class functions. Is it not possible to use the same method for mapping to properties as well?

Comment: You can't update class properties after PHP's preprocessing, period. You will need to send an AJAX request or communicate somehow else to the server with the updated property.

Comment: In addition, I don't think many of us know or understand what `AddJsonHook` is/does. Google doesn't provide many results.

Comment: OMG! You're right tdlive aw'sum. It seems to be part of their proprietary mechanism. I'll try and see if I could use jQuery or XHR. Thanks for your answers.